# PHP5 giving failed to open stream: HTTP request failed error when using fopen

Tags: php, fopen

This problem seems to have been discussed in the past everywhere on google and here, but I have yet to find a solution.

A very simple fopen gives me a

> PHP Warning:  fopen(http://www.google.ca): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!".

The URL I am fetching have no importance because even when I fetch http://www.google.com it doesnt work. The exact same script works on different server. The one failing is Ubuntu 10.04 and PHP 5.3.2. This is not a problem in my script, it's something different in my server or it might be a bug in PHP.

I have tried using a user_agent in php.ini but no success. My allow_url_fopen is set to On.

If you have any ideas, feel free!

Comment: Can you do a `wget http://www.google.ca` from the command line? Is `fopen()` not giving any more error information?

Comment: can you do fopen('173.194.43.104') ? (that's google.ca's ip) maybe DSN isn't accessible by PHP on that server?

Comment: @Pekka yes, I can fetch no problem this way

Comment: @Viper_Sb: no difference DNS is working correctly, and everything else is, I can wget or lynx to the webserver, it's just fopen

Comment: that's why I said perhaps it's not accessible by PHP, it could be working just fine but PHP doesn't have access to it.

Answer (score 11):

It sounds like your configuration isn't allowed to use file functions, which is common these days because of security concerns. If you have the cURL libraries available to you, I would recommend trying those out.

[PHP: cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.google.ca/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$file = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $file;
```

Comment: Create a test PHP file with the `phpinfo();` line it. Search for "curl" and see if it's enabled.

Comment: Ok I see you edited your post, that version is working, i'll try it in my script.

Comment: @mickey If this worked for you in your script, go ahead and accept this answer!

Comment: still trying to work it out... I'd rather like to find a solution as to why the fopen function is not working, since I have many scripts using this function.

Answer (score 1):

Check that your php.ini config is set to allow fopen to open external URL's:

```
allow_url_fopen "1"
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen

Comment: this is set to "On" by default in my Ubuntu installation

Answer (score 1):

I'm not at all sure about whether this is the problem or not, but I know in the past I've had problems with opening URLs with fopen, often due to php.ini's allow_url_fopen or other unknown security settings

You may want to try [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) in PHP, which often works for me, you'll find an example really easily by googling that.

Comment: The exact same one? Strange. What does curl_error() give?  http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php

Answer (score 0):

Check your `phpinfo` output - is `http` present under `Registered PHP Streams`?

Comment: https, ftps, compress.zlib, compress.bzip2, php, file, glob, data, http, ftp, phar, zip

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting "HTTP request failed" without further details? The socket timeout could be expired. This default to 60 seconds. See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-set-timeout.php